# Disable background touch SpriteKit iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit

I'm making a simple game that recognises touches on specific nodes and it works when I click on that specific node it `NSLog(@"correct");` if clicked on another node `NSLog(@"wrong");` I recognise the `wrong` node using this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"correct"]){
        NSLog(@"correct");
    }else if (![node.name isEqualToString:@"correct"]){
        NSLog(@"Wrong");
    }
}
```

that works well but when I click on the background it `NSLog(@"Wrong")` I want to disable background touches. How can I disable it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: May I ask you to add more code? How you are adding the nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You must be using some like `SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];` in your touchesBegan method. That being the case, check if node == nil. If yes, you are not touching a node.

If you have a background or worldNode, add code to check, by assigning it a unique name, if the background node is being touched.

Comment: Add your code inside another if block - if (![node.name isEqualToString:@"background"]){...your if/else block here...}

Comment: Thanks a lot @sangony